# How can I use a CASE in a SELECT in BigQuery if a field exactly matches one or more text strings (words)?

Tags: select, google-bigquery, case

What I want to do is to do something (THEN) when another field contains either 'Click video' or 'Click button'

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN field IS EXACTLY 'Click video' or 'Click button' THEN do something to another field
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler approach I see

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN field in ('Click video', 'Click button') 
  THEN do something to another field
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [IF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#if) or [CASE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case_expr):

```
WITH Numbers AS
 (SELECT 10 as A, 20 as B UNION ALL
  SELECT 50, 30 UNION ALL
  SELECT 60, 60)
SELECT
  A, B,
  IF( A<B, 'true', 'false') as result
FROM Numbers


WITH Numbers AS
 (SELECT 90 as A, 2 as B UNION ALL
  SELECT 50, 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 60, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 50, 10)
SELECT A, B,
  CASE A
    WHEN 90 THEN 'red'
    WHEN 50 THEN 'blue'
    ELSE 'green'
  END
  AS result
FROM Numbers


WITH Numbers AS
 (SELECT 90 as A, 2 as B UNION ALL
  SELECT 50, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 20, 10)
SELECT A, B,
  CASE
    WHEN A > 60 THEN 'red'
    WHEN A > 30 THEN 'blue'
    ELSE 'green'
  END
  AS result
FROM Numbers
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make it simpler, like with REGEXP_CONTAINS or something similar?

Comment: `REGEXP_CONTAINS(field, r'Click video|Click button')` will work, but it may incur a bit larger overhead in terms of compute resource usage